# Change ActionBar Background Color in code from Navigation List

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the color of the Action Bar background when the user chooses a selection in the Navigation List.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if(itemPosition == 0)
        {
            colorDrawable.setColor(0xffFEBB31);
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
            return true;
        }
        if(itemPosition == 1)
        {
            colorDrawable.setColor(0xff9ACC00);
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However, the first time I select itemPosition 1 in the Navigation List, it changes the ActionBar color to white.

[image]
The second time I click the itemPosition 1 in the Navigation List, I have no issue.

[image]
Could anyone tell me why this is and how I can fix the problem? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
myActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 10):

Try using this code:

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffFEBB31"));
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing as the original poster asked did, only with a slightly different way of choosing the colour. It does nothing to fix the problem.

Comment: I've used this before and it works. Changing it to use the hex method that Tykin mentions does exactly what the question states. Perhaps someone could provide some insight into why Tykin's method does not work for this situation.

Comment: This works. I just changed 0x to # and it worked fine, any idea why?

Comment: @JMint The docs state that the "Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue' ... " 0x is what you would use if it were looking for an `int` as a parameter (such as with the method `public static int rgb (int red, int green, int blue)`). Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem.

For Xamarin Users in Visual Studio or the like.

Please paste this just after the SetContentView(Resource.Layou...... in the activity class.

`// Setting ActionBar (Toolbar) background color natively
var actionBar = this.ActionBar;
actionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Black));`

You may change it as you deem necessary of do more on the actionBar variable.

Thanks hope this helps.