# How to change navigation bar drop down menu fount color in ABS?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Hello I'm using ABS in my application on a screen I an using navigation drop down controller. But the text of drop down is coming in black color and I want them in white color. Is there any way to change the font color of drop down list in navigation bar? I'm using custom theme for ABS which is from  [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100)

Answer (score 0):

Change the Background Color on an Action Bar

1. Add Action Bar to your project.
2. Open the ActivityMain.java file and add the below imports to the imports section.

   import android.app.ActionBar;
   import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
3. Then, in the ActivityMain.java file add the below to the onCreate method.

   ```
      ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
      ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#81a3d0"));     
      ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
   ```
4. Determine the Hex color you would like and update the Color.parColor above to your specific color.
5. Compile and run!

Resources:
[Change ActionBar Background Color in code from Navigation List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770512/change-actionbar-background-color-in-code-from-navigation-list)