# Change ActionBar color - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

i've got a small question about the `ActionBar` in Android.
I am using Xamarin Studio to make an application and i would like to change the color of the ActionBar. I've looked far and wide for a way to change the color but this is the only thing that i could find.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#ff0f62ae"));
            this.ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

I tought this would work but now i get this exception and i cannot figure out why this isnt working for me.

This is the exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Can someone explain to me what i am doeing wrong and maybe show me how i can fix this.

**Edit**

After an couple of comments i've tried this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme"
           parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/</item>
        <item name="andriod:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

How can i add a custom color, and how do i assign this to my actionbar

Comment: I think you can create a style take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: I tought the above would be possible because someone tried it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770512/change-actionbar-background-color-in-code-from-navigation-list Someone said it works

Comment: Yes it might work but if you have a pattern that makes everything clean I think you can try. If it doesn't work we need to see why? But please try yo create your style

Comment: ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));

Comment: getActionBar doesnt work for me

Comment: Look there is tutorial is old but I think you can try http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/xamarin-adding-custom-title-bar-in-android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did in this way. Try this and let me know if it works please,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_action_bar</item>
</style> "
```

And in colors.xml or add color variable in strings.xml, please add your desired color for the action bar

```
<color name="color_action_bar">#3450A3</color>
```

And mention the theme in the manifest file

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: @Mayank please make sure that in your custom App Theme  windowActionBar is turned off and NoTitle is turned on.`<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:


<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#f00</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: How and where do i include this in my program

Comment: I have to make styles.XML and put that in the resources folder. or do i put it in another folde

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
   <color name="actionBarBackgroundColor">#2C3E50</color>
    <color name="actionBarTextColor">#FFFFFF</color>
  <style name="MyAppTheme"/>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>         
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ActionBar">
      <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
      <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarBackgroundColor</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionBarTextColor</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an explanation upon @SID's answer , For styling your Actionbar you have to override the whole theme of your app.

If they don't exist add `Styles.XML` and `Colors.XML` files under `Resource>values` folder and edit them as below :

Styles.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/DarkBlue</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Colors.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="DarkBlue">#007acc</color> 
</resources>
```

Now navigate to `Properties>AndroidManifest.xml` and change the `<application>` tag to reference your customized theme :

```
  <application 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
     ... >

  </application>
```

**UPDATE :**

If you are willing to use `AppCompat` and `ActionBarActivity` then you will no longer need the `ActionBarTheme` in `Styles.XML` so here is what `Styles.XML` will look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/LightBlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/DarkBlue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Pink</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

And the `Colors.XML` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <color name="DarkBlue">#0052cc</color>
  <color name="Pink">#ff1ac6</color>
  <color name="LightBlue">#1a75ff</color>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is my solution, i used your code with some slight modifications and it worked, attached is a picture sample of the result code and below is your code plus my modified ver[image]sion of your code

```
//Define ActionBar
       actionbar=SupportActionBar;
//Define Color Drawable
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#ff0f62ae"));
//Set drawable color to ActionBar
    actionbar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution, go to your "styles.xml" file on your Xamarin.Android project, and just replace or add this properties to your style:

```
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->    
<item name="colorPrimary">#002500</item>
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar #4FAB5B-->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#002500</item>
```